# Specify a "too large" level when converting numeric to factor in R

Tags: r, r-factor

When converting a numeric value to a factor, can I specify the level values at which the conversion occurs? Is it possible to designate a special level as "`too large`" or say "`5+`" without defining a(n inline) function?

For example:

```
c(1,2,20,3,10)
```

would be converted to:

```
factor(c("1","2","many","3","many"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use cut, e.g.,

```
v = c(1,2,20,3,10)
cut(v, c(0:5, Inf), labels = c(1:5, "many"), right = T, include.lowest = T)
```

yields

```
 [1] 1    2    many 3    many
 Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 many
```

cut has a number of additional parameters to control how values get placed in the bins, so read the help there.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a very simple way would be to do something along the lines of

```
x = c(1,2,20,3,10)
f = x
f[f>5] = "many"
f = factor(f)
```

There is probably a more elegant way to do this specifying something in the levels parameter of the factor function. Still playing with this.

Comment: I like this better than `cut`.

Comment: cut will probably scale much better if you are dealing with large amounts of data. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is reasonable to require it to be done "without defining a(n inline) function". However,

```
x<-c(1,2,20,3,10)
factor("[<-"(x, x>9, "many"))
```

... does it as there is already such a function (`[<-`).

[[edit]] The solution with `cut` above seems more readable.

alternatively:

```
factor(ifelse(x>9, "many", x))
```

Comment: `factor(replace(x,x>9,'many'))` will be slightly more readable than using `"[<-"`.